# error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server:-provider: Named Pipes Provider

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008r2-express

I created a Windows Forms application using C# and SQL Server 2008 R2 as back-end. I also created a click-once installer package by adding Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 as a prerequisites.

If I install my application on computer that have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed it works fine.

But instead if I install on newly installed operating system (Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit) if do no run shows error

> provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong with my application.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 **Express** - then you must add a pre-requisite for SQL Server **Express** (and *not* Compact edition!) to your click-once installer! SQL Server Compact is quite a different beast, using `.sdf` data files.

Comment: I Have already added SQL Server 2008 R2 pre-requisite.